# Python Openpyxl Writing in a cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I cannot seem to write any value in an excel sheet. I open two files at the same time. I want to copy a value from file 1 to file 2. it gives the error

```
File

"C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\dump_worksheet.py", line 214, in removed_method
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Only the line with the writing part gives an error. The function code is as follows

```
def data_input(size):

    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb1 = load_workbook('150318 load matching_Storage_v4.xlsm',data_only=True)
    wb1s1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Home load options')

    from openpyxl import Workbook
    wb2 = Workbook('Data',write_only=True)
    wb2s1 = wb2.create_sheet(0)
    wb2s1.title = "Consumption"

    wb2s1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = 4 - this line gives the error

    #what i have to write but block yet to test if i can write at all
    '''i = 0
    r = 0
    while i < 8760:
        d = wb2s1.cell(row = r, column = 1)
        d.value = i
        i = i + 0.25
        r += 1'''


    for i in range(4,35040):
        cell_value1 = wb1s1.cell(row = i, column = (12+size)).value
        print(cell_value1)
     #   cell_value1 = wb2s1.cell(row = i-3, column = 1) 
    wb2.save('Data.xlsx')
```

I tried all the different ways in the documentation but nothing works so far.

please help.

Thank you

Comment: should i use the append method ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a **write-only** workbook. At the name suggests, this is designed for streaming data to a workbook so some operations, such as looking up cells do not work. To add data you should use the `append()` method. If you do need to add formatting or comments to individual cells you can include a `WriteOnlyCell` in the iterable that you pass into `append()`.

Comment: actually wanted to read and write so i will delete the write only argument. Do you know the arguments to be given to the append function if variations both row wise and column wise are to be made. It isnt clear from the documentation on the openpyxl webpage.

Comment: is there anyway to write simple float values to individual cells with an iterative process.